# Raspberry pi 3 boot partition gets corrupted over and over

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot-issues, backup

I have a very hard problem with my raspi. Well, this is the steps I follow:

- Write a raspbian jessie lite or PiBakery into the SD Card.
- Boot from the pi, no problem
- Set internationalization
- Update, upgrade, rpi-upgrade and install python3.4, dolphin and leafpad
- Shutdown the raspberry
- Go to Ubuntu and use dd or clonezilla. Here I start to see errors on the SD, but before I updated the raspbian I have 0 problems.
- The I inserted the sd again in to the raspi and it won't boot again.

fsck does nothing. I tried with and without it. The SD card is a Samsung SDHC 16 Gb, I saw it in this wiki too http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Which_SD_card.3F.

Any advice or tip for help?

### Update:

It seems to happen after the first boot with a fresh install. The boot partition gets corrupted and if I connect it to another device they didn't read it or say taht is corruped. If I do an fsck or a dd I can't boot again.

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? How are you shutting down? Have you tried a second card?

Comment: Sudo shutdown. Wait a minute after the last led. Remove the power and the card. I use the oficial power supply 2.5A

Comment: O didn't try other sd but this sd only gived problems after updating the raspbian, never before or writing other things.

Comment: If you are consistently "seeing errors" using `dd`, that is **not** filesystem corruption, that is a physically damaged/defective/defunct card.

Comment: I'll try another 2 sd and come with the results.

Comment: You might also want to make explicit *exactly* what you mean by "seeing errors" using `dd`.  My last comment applies if you are literally getting I/O errors reported while running `dd`, because the nature of the data involved is completely meaningless to it.  You can take a card filled with destroyed data and `dd` as much of it off as you want, and likewise take random junk and `dd` it to a card, and there should be no errors reported.  If there are, it means somewhere along the line there are **hardware problems** (or possibly software bugs, but hardware failure is more likely in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Many SD cards do not work very well with the Raspberry PI. That link you [posted](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Which_SD_card.3F) is the first place to look at

But even with a well tested SD card, it is very important to poweroff the raspberry PI from the command line `sudo halt`, then cut power, then extract the SD.

These things are delicate...

Comment: What is the purpose of posting a link from a question as an answer? Also OP mentions they "shutdown the Raspberry", so it's likely not an unclean shutdown.

Comment: "Many" may be an exaggeration but there are definitely *some* cards that do not work with the model A/B.  I think this is true to a lesser extent with the microSD based models...in particular some big (64 GB+) cards, but I may be remembering that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely `rpi-update`

"In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911